# How to invoke two functions when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

Here is my button

```
# Delete button
deleteButton = QtGui.QPushButton("X", self)
deleteButton.clicked[bool].connect(lambda: self.delete_listener(listener))
```

I would like to do something like

```
deleteButton.clicked[bool].connect(lambda: self.delete_listener(listener))
deleteButton.clidked[bool].connect(lambda: self.stop_send_data())
```

The easiest way I can think of is to make

```
delete_listener
```

call

```
stop_send_data
```

But is there anyway I can circumvent that?

Comment: As @Trilarion correctly answered, the two lines you would like to have are perfectly valid. Qt will simply call one connected slot after the others.

Answer (score 7):

> I would like to do something like..

And did you do it? Because it actually works. In Qt you can connect a single signal with several slots. The order of execution might not be guaranteed though so it should not matter. But in case the order is important you can do what user2600939 suggests (putting both actions into a single action).

Small example for two actions done upon one click:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

button = QtGui.QPushButton('Click me')
button.clicked.connect(lambda: print('tip'))
button.clicked.connect(lambda: print('top'))
button.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a method that calls both of those methods...

```
class ClassName:
    #init and other methods...

    def deleteButtonMethod(self,listener):
        self.delete_listener(listener)
        self.stop_send_data()
```

then call your method when button is clicked with

```
deleteButton.clicked[bool].connect(lambda: self.deleteButtonMethod(listener))
```

I have no experience with pyside so I left the lambda in you can probably just call...
    deleteButton.clicked[bool].connect(self.deleteButtonMethod(listener))

Comment: The last line will fail in Python at runtime (independent of PySide or not) because the interpreter will execute the `deleteButtonMethod` method immediately. Language syntax is in the way. You have to provide a callable that can be called later. `self.deleteButtonMethod(listener)` is not a callable.

Answer (score 0):

when i was working on a project i had the same problem but on my project it was needed inside exec(...) and using a lambda turned Pyqt widgets into bool so i made this

```
class tools:
  class Func(object):
    def combine(val,functions,args,type):
        v=list()
        for data in val:
            v.append(data)

        sargs=list()
        for i,func in enumerate(functions):
            if type[i]=='one str':
                sargs.append( partial(
                        func,
                        args[i]
                        )
                    )
            if type[i]=='normal':
                sargs.append( partial(
                        func,
                        *args[i]
                        )
                    )
                

        return {'s':sargs,'v':v}
    def execCFunc(cfunc):
        v=cfunc['v']
        for func in cfunc['s']:
            func()
```

example use

```
import sys
import sys 
import os
from functools import partial
import shutil
import ast

class tools:
  class Func(object):
    def combine(val,functions,args,type):
        v=list()
        for data in val:
            v.append(data)

        sargs=list()
        for i,func in enumerate(functions):
            if type[i]=='one str':
                sargs.append( partial(
                        func,
                        args[i]
                        )
                    )
            if type[i]=='normal':
                sargs.append( partial(
                        func,
                        *args[i]
                        )
                    )
                

        return {'s':sargs,'v':v}
    def execCFunc(cfunc):
        v=cfunc['v']
        for func in cfunc['s']:
            func()          

<...>

savenn.clicked[bool].connect( partial(
                        tools.Func.execCFunc,
                            (
                            tools.Func.combine(
                            (name,"''"),
                                (
                                    (savenn.move),
                                    (exec)
                                ),
                                (
                                    (1500,5),
                                    ("os.rename(str(se{td}.get('cwd'))+str(se{td}.get('on'))+'.XAPF',str(se{td}.get('cwd'))+str(v[0].text())+'.XAPF');se{td}.set('on',v[0].text());print('saved')")
                                ),
                                (
                                    'normal',
                                    'one str'
                                )
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 

name.textChanged[str].connect(
                    partial(
                        tools.Func.execCFunc,
                            (
                            tools.Func.combine(
                            ('""',"''"),
                                (
                                    (savenn.move),
                                    (se{td}.set)
                                ),
                                (
                                    (150,5),
                                    ('nn',name.text())
                                ),
                                (
                                    'normal',
                                    'normal'
                                )
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                )
```